# Filter "coffee is not defined error in HAML 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, coffeescript, haml

For some reason my deployed rails app is now giving me a:

**Haml::Error in Explore#index**

**Filter "coffee" is not defined.**

...after updating to latest version rails and latest haml 4.

Locally, I do not get this error. Haml version 4 should support the coffee filter. All other filters seem to work fine.

Here's the bundle list on the deploy server:

```
actionmailer (3.2.12)
actionpack (3.2.12)
activemodel (3.2.12)
activerecord (3.2.12)
activeresource (3.2.12)
activesupport (3.2.12)
addressable (2.3.2)
anjlab-bootstrap-rails (2.3.0.0)
arel (3.0.2)
aws-sdk (1.3.9)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.2.1)
capistrano (2.14.2)
cocaine (0.4.2)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
devise (2.2.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
faraday (0.8.5)
font-awesome-sass-rails (3.0.2.1)
haml (4.0.0)
haml-rails (0.4)
hashie (1.2.0)
highline (1.6.15)
hike (1.2.1)
httparty (0.10.2)
httpauth (0.2.0)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.0)
jquery-rails (2.2.1)
json (1.7.7)
jwt (0.1.5)
kgio (2.8.0)
koala (1.6.0)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.21)
multi_json (1.6.1)
multi_xml (0.5.3)
multipart-post (1.1.5)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
net-scp (1.1.0)
net-sftp (2.1.1)
net-ssh (2.6.5)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
oauth2 (0.8.0)
omniauth (1.1.3)
omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
paperclip (3.4.0)
paperclip-remote (0.5.0)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rabl (0.8.0)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.12)
railties (3.2.12)
raindrops (0.10.0)
rake (10.0.3)
rdoc (3.12.1)
right_aws (3.0.4)
right_http_connection (1.3.0)
rmagick (2.13.2)
rocket_tag (0.5.6)
sass (3.2.5)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
sprockets (2.2.2)
squeel (1.0.16)
sugar-rails (1.3.7)
thor (0.17.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
twitter-text (1.5.0)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
uglifier (1.3.0)
unicorn (4.6.0)
uuidtools (2.1.3)
warden (1.2.1)
will_paginate (3.0.4)
```

Simple coffee filter:

```
%html
...
:coffee
  alert "hello"
```

Comment: Do you have a an execjs compatible JavaScript runtime on your production instance?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you're using an [execjs](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs) compatible runtime in production. If you're deploying to Window or Mac OS, or you have node.js installed in production, you should be fine.

Then, be sure to restart the application in production after adding any gems. It seems that the coffee filter would only be loaded after restarting the server in production (see https://github.com/paulnicholson/coffee-filter/issues/6).